# PHP-FPM its anatomy

Tags: php, nginx

Since PHP-fpm wiki is down and different sources tell me to do different things i decided to post it here and clarify few things

> PHP-FPM compiles and executes the PHP script, sending the output back
>   to the web server.

Currently i am using nginx as a proxy server, the plan is to send all request that require dynamic content to PHP-fpm from nginx. And question immidiatly raised, can i have multiple machines running php-fpm ? (scaling and stuff), answer i found bellow.

> Although requests pass via a proxy connection, the PHP-FPM service
>   must run on the same server as the web server. @inmotionhosting.com

Which sounds like a logical thing since i am passing `$document_root` param for it to load php files from.

My question is: How exactly php-fpm locates the file it needs to execute ? what other params i can pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple machines running PHP-FPM. This implies that you have to synchronize the files between the instances.

> PHP-FPM service must run on the same server as the web server

The statement is not really correct. Web server can be on one machine, and a PHP-FPM instance can be on the other. PHP-FPM can listen on a network socket(port) in this case. And as long as web server (NGINX), tells PHP-FPM the filename to render that exists on the PHP-FPM server, it can get the response from it, and render for the client. This makes sense for scaling.

For single server setup (no scaling), you'd have a standard setup of everything on the same server; and PHP-FPM bound to / listening on a UNIX socket, and not network.

PHP-FPM is a [FastCGI](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html) server so it's supposed to follow the protocol. It doesn't really locate anything, this is what NGINX does. Once it did, it then passes the located filename in `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter/environment variable, while talking to PHP-FPM; that is among few other [parameters](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/fastcgi_params)

To influence how NGINX locates the files, you can use the directives:

- `root`
- `rewrite`
- `alias`
- `index`
- `fastcg_param`

E.g. say we have a standard "front-controller" website written in PHP. The following is NGINX config essentials used by it:

```
root /var/www/html;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What happens when visitor hits `/foo/bar` URL?

- NGINX looks at the longest prefix-based location, which is `/` and chooses it for current request
- It also checks for any regex locations but finds none that match to the URI
- So it attempts to actually see if there is `root` directive's value + `/foo/bar` file on its system. That is, it checks using a `stat` system call, whether `/var/www/html/foo/bar` exists. If the file indeed exists, it will just serve it
- If the file does not exist, then NGINX attempts to see if `/var/www/html/foo/bar/` directory exists. It it does, then NGINX will check the existence of files defined by `index` directive (e.g. `index.html`) in a defined order, and use those to satisfy requests (if they do exist), e.g. `/var/www/html/foo/bar/index.html`
- If those do not exist, NGINX finally knows it needs to serve using `/index.php`. How the `try_files` works is that "reaching" its last argument will result in another location search, and this time it will match the regex location of `\.php$`.

That's where the magic of talking to PHP-FPM will happen, as in NGINX will pass on the script filename which is constructed off `root` and *current*, internally rewritten request URI. How it is constructed can be configured using the ngx_http_fastcgi_module nginx module directives which are documented [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html)